# Invoking AWS Step Function from API Gateway and returning response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

From my understanding, API Gateway can trigger the Step Function. To kick off our state machine execution we need to send a post request as input.

The issue I am coming across is that API gateway will not wait for the execution to finish so it is no way of allowing the step function to respond back to the request:

Below is an image to outline this.

[image]

If this is in fact true, is there a way to call a lambda from within my lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is true, any invocation of Step Functions will immediately return a success response with an execution ARN that can be used to track the execution status.

> If this is in fact true, is there a way to call a lambda from within
> my lambda?

Yes absolutely, via the AWS SDK for the programming language you are using you can call the Lambda `invoke()` method. Although if you have one Lambda waiting on another Lambda to finish executing, be aware that you are going to be doubling the AWS Lambda charges you incur.

Comment: is this still true? is there still no way to return custom response from Step Function?

Comment: @ShadabFaiz It looks like there is a new option: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-synchronous-express-workflows-for-aws-step-functions/